# Why does not negative margin-top work within flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

[Example to show the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/2e9yL6k1/19/)

As we can see, the #a2 only moves up 50px, which was expected to move up 100px.

Can someone explain this for me? It confuses me for days..

```css
#container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#a1{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
}
#a2{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: -100px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a1">
  
  </div>
  <div id="a2">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `align-items:center`

Answer (score 0):

The `#a2` moves only `-50px` because you have used `align-items:center` for the container which uses `display:flex`.This will let the div `#a2` to center vertically.Removing it will solve your problem.

while using `display:flex`, you can center the contents horizontally using `justify-content:center` and for centering vertically use `align-items:center`

If you need more information on this topic refer this : [Aligning Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

**See this sample code:**

```css
#container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: center;*/ /*Removed align-items:center*/
}
#a1{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
}
#a2{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: -100px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="a1"></div>
    <div id="a2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove align-items:center and give margin-top:100px to div #a1

```css
#container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;

}
#a1{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top:100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#a2{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;

  right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a1">
  
  </div>
  <div id="a2">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your kind replies.
However, I use align-items: center on purpose.

After experiments, I think the key reason for this is **the order**.
In this scenario, margin-top: -100px first expands the container. Then it vertically centers the div.

And note this: it is quite different from centering first then applying the margin-top: -100px.